# Maximum Array Length Quota Exception in WCF

Tags: wcf, readerquotas

I am writing a WCF service to upload files but it throws an exceptions when byte array has more than 16384 elements.

This is the exception detail:

> The formatter threw an exception while
>   trying to deserialize the message:
>   Error in deserializing body of request
>   message for operation
>   'CreateDocument'. The maximum array
>   length quota (16384) has been exceeded
>   while reading XML data. This quota may
>   be increased by changing the
>   MaxArrayLength property on the
>   XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used
>   when creating the XML reader. Line 1,
>   position 22862.

The config for both client and server sets the maximum array length quota to 2147483647.

Client Config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
   <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IDocumentLibraryService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
     openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
     allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
     maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
     messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
     useDefaultWebProxy="true">
     <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
      maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
     <security mode="None">
      <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
       realm="" />
      <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
     </security>
    </binding>
   </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
   <endpoint address="http://localhost:50764/DocumentLibraryService.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IDocumentLibraryService"
    contract="DocumentLibrary.IDocumentLibraryService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IDocumentLibraryService" />
  </client>
```

Server Config:

```
<bindings>

            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IDocumentLibraryService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                 openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                 allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                 maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                 messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                 useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
                maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                         realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <services>

            <service name="BasicHttpBinding_IDocumentLibraryService">

                <clear />
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="mex" contract="Peninsula.DocumentLibrary.ServiceLayer.IDocumentLibraryService" />
                <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" name="DocumentLibraryService" contract="Peninsula.DocumentLibrary.ServiceLayer.IDocumentLibraryService" address=""
                          bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IDocumentLibraryService"/>
            </service>
        </services>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I needed to do was to change Service name in web.config file to full service name with namespace:

```
<service name="SampleNameSpace.DocumentLibraryService">

                <clear />
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="mex" contract="Peninsula.DocumentLibrary.ServiceLayer.IDocumentLibraryService" />
                <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" name="DocumentLibraryService" contract="Peninsula.DocumentLibrary.ServiceLayer.IDocumentLibraryService" address=""
                          bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IDocumentLibraryService"/>
            </service>
```

Comment: This times 1000!!  I lost 2 days of banging my head against a wall, trying to figure out what was wrong with my configuration.  I had all the proper quotas set, and was still getting the error.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer since your configuration seems OK. I think you just need to check these values in the code (output to trace or debug) on the **service host** and the **proxy** to make sure the same values in config are loaded into your channels.

On possibility is that another threshold is reached and the error is misleading

Now I **strongly advise against using byte array to upload files** especially if you use XML. These will be represented as XML arrays and the structure will be hugely bloated XML which will take 10 times more than the original file.

I would use:

- [WCF Streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731913.aspx) which works with basic binding as well and is *super fast*
- alternatively represent the byte array as **base64** string. This will take 33% more space but not 1000%

---

## UPDATE

You can trace the binding name that was used to configure the service (use it inside any of your WCF operations):

```
public int MyServiceOperation()
{
     Trace.WriteLine(OperationContext.Current.EndpointDispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.BindingName)
....
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ali Jan, My service is hosted on IIS. How can I check these values on IIS?